# Java Concurrent Modification Exception: How to deal with?

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification

I'm writing a text file crawler program and keep getting a ConcurrentModificationException. I know it has something to do with using Iterator but I'm not sure how to fix it. Please help!

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(unknown Source)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at TextCrawler.main(TextCrawler.java:112)
```

Code:

```
while(it1.hasNext() && wordCount2 < wordCountToFind2) { //while there are more files to be searched and the wordCount is less than max occurrences 
           wordCount2 = 0;
           Iterator it3 = occurrencesVector.iterator();
           while(it3.hasNext()) { //get current wordCount
             wordCount = (Integer)it3.next();
             wordCount2 += wordCount;
             System.out.println("WordCount2...." + wordCount2); //Test
           }
           String nextFile = (String)it1.next(); //this is line 112
           System.out.println("nextFile...." + nextFile + "\n" + "\n"); //Test
           if(i > 0) { //skips the initial input filename (which is at the start of filenameSet) so it's not checked twice
             System.out.println("Start searchFile method"); //Test
             try{txtCr2.searchFile(nextFile, wordToFind2, wordCountToFind, caseSensitive);} //call searchFile method
             catch(IOException e){System.out.println("txtCr2 exception, searchFile method didn't happen!"); e.printStackTrace();};
           }
           i++;
           System.out.println("i = " + i);
         }
```

Full code for searchFile method:

```
public void searchFile(String filename, String wordTF, String wordCountTF, String caseS) throws IOException
 {
    FileReader aFileReader = new FileReader(new File(filename)); //make the file readable
    BufferedReader aBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(aFileReader);
    String newFile, lineFromFile, updatedLine = "", filePattern = "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,32}.txt\\)", outputMessage = "";
    char aChar;
    int wordCount = 0, occurrencesToFind;
    occurrencesToFind = Integer.parseInt(wordCountTF); //convert passed down String to int
    filenameSet.add(new String(filename)); //add the filename to the LindedHashSet

    while((lineFromFile = aBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { //while lineFromFile is not empty
      for(int i = 0; i < lineFromFile.length(); i++) { 
        aChar = lineFromFile.charAt(i); //go through each line character by character
        if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(aChar) || Character.isWhitespace(aChar) || aChar == '(' || aChar == ')' || aChar == '.') 
          if(aChar == '(') //if the character is ( then add a space in front of it
            updatedLine = updatedLine +  " " + aChar;  
          else
          if(aChar == ')') //if the character is ) then add a space after it
            updatedLine = updatedLine + aChar + " ";
          else
            updatedLine = updatedLine + aChar; //if the character is a letter, digit or whitespace just add it to the updatedLine
      }    //all unwanted punctuation is removed
    } 
    aFileReader.close();
    aBufferedReader.close();

    String [] fileArray = updatedLine.toLowerCase().split(" "); //split the updatedLine into an array at the whitespaces.

    //for(int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) //Test
      //System.out.println(fileArray[i]);

    boolean fileSearched = false;

    while(wordCount < occurrencesToFind && !fileSearched) { //while the wordCount is less than the required wordCount and the file hasn't been completely searched.
      if(caseS.equals("1")) { //if the word to be checked is case sensitive
        for(int j = 0; j < fileArray.length; j++) { //for the length of the array
          if(fileArray[j].equals(wordTF)) //if a word in the fileArray exactly equals the word to be searched
            wordCount++; //add a count of one to the wordCount
          if(fileArray[j].matches(filePattern)) { //if a word in the fileArray matches the filePattern e.g. (filename.txt)
            newFile = fileArray[j].substring(1,fileArray[j].length() -1); //newFile is equal to the filePattern with round brackets removed.
            System.out.println("New File found..." + newFile); //Test
            filenameSet.add(new String(newFile)); //add it to the LinkedHashSet
          }
        }
        fileSearched = true; //file has been searched
      }
      else { //else if the word to be checked isn't case sensitive
        for(int j = 0; j < fileArray.length; j++) { //for the length of the array
          if(fileArray[j].toLowerCase().equals(wordTF.toLowerCase())) //not case sensitive so make both search word and fileArray word lower case
            wordCount++; //if they are equal add a count of one to the word count
          if(fileArray[j].matches(filePattern)) { //if a word in the fileArray matches the filePattern e.g. (filename.txt)
            newFile = fileArray[j].substring(1,fileArray[j].length() -1); //newFile is equal to the filePattern with round brackets removed.
            System.out.println("New File found...." + newFile); //Test
            filenameSet.add(newFile); //add it to the LinkedHashSet
          }
        }
        fileSearched = true; //file has been searched
      }
    }
    occurrencesVector.addElement(new Integer(wordCount)); //add the wordCount to the occurrences LinkedHashSet
    System.out.println("occurrencesVector contains.." + occurrencesVector); //Test
    System.out.println("filenameSet contains.." + filenameSet);  //Test
    System.out.println("End of searchFile method.\n\n"); //Test
 }
```

occurrencesVector:

```
public class TextCrawler
{
 static LinkedHashSet<String> filenameSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
 static Vector<Integer> occurrencesVector = new Vector<Integer>();
```

it1:

```
System.out.println("\nStarting initial file search in..." + startFile2);
         try{txtCr.searchFile(startFile2, wordToFind2, wordCountToFind, caseSensitive);}
         catch(IOException e){System.out.println("txtCr exception");};

         boolean nextFileSearched = false;
         int wordCount, wordCount2 = 0, wordCount3, wordCount4 = 0; 
         Iterator it1 = filenameSet.iterator();
         Iterator it2 = occurrencesVector.iterator();
         int i = 0;

         while(it2.hasNext()) { //get current wordCount
           wordCount = (Integer)it2.next();
           wordCount2 += wordCount;
         }

         while(it1.hasNext() && wordCount2 < wordCountToFind2) { //while there are more files to be searched and the wordCount is less than max occurrences 
           wordCount2 = 0;
```

Comment: This generally happens when you call `someCollection.remove(someItem);` while iterating over it. You need to replace that by `anIteratorOnTheCollection.remove();`. Does your `searchFile` method try to remove something from the collection on which `it1` is iterating?

Comment: Normally you'd want to include things like the line where the exception occurs; we don't know which line 112 is.

Comment: `someCollection.remove(someItem)` or `someCollection.add(someItem);` cause ConcurrentModificationException while an iteration is currently carried out.

Comment: This code seems valid, therefore add a bit more info about your code, what is `it1`, `occurrencesVector`, `searchFile()`

Comment: Line 112 is marked in a comment, and it is just "String nextFile = (String)it1.next();". This is just the line that detects the modification. Presumably, the collection that it1 iterates is being modified other than through it1, probably in code that is not shown above.

Comment: Sorry, full code for the searchFile method is now added. I do add an item in the code. Can you tell me how to prevent this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConcurrentModificationException means that you are using an "expired" iterator.

The iterator is "expired" since the collection it is currently crawling has changed.

Here is a great code example to demonstrate:

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3);

    Iterator<Integer> i1 = l.iterator();

    System.out.println(i1.next());
    System.out.println(i1.next());

    // Here we modify the content of "l"
    l.add(4);

    // After modifying the content of "l" we try to get the next element of the iterator: this will throw an exception
    System.out.println(i1.next());
}
```